# Unable to focus when using ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting Webdriver exception "Failed to send keys because cannot focus on element" while using ChromeDriver.
I have also observed that if I bring up any other window (say eclipse) in front of the chrome browser and then minimize it, the ChromeDriver is able to resume execution on the Chrome browser but gets stuck again on the next input field.
Can anyone please help suggest some solution

Comment: Post the relevant code and html.

Comment: Could you please provide detailed information...Such as Error/Exception and the your script code ..?

Comment: Update the question with _code trials_, relevant _HTML_ and _error stack trace_.

Comment: yes code is needed and relevant HTML.

Comment: You can use TAB with sends keys to make it in focus

Comment: I down-voted this question because it's been fourteen hours with no response from the original poster on providing detailed information.  I don't know how it even got an up-vote to begin with since the post is not well-constructed at all.

Comment: Apologies for the delay but I won't be able to share details about the HTML or code due to security policies. I understand if it is not possible to assist or suggest anything further without these details but thanks to all who took time to read and comment.